# Ask - accessing built in notes app IOS and Android - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

is it possible to open Notes app on Ios and Android when the phone has built in Notes app ?

i cannot find any package or apps name (trying to deeplink) the Notes apps on both android and ios.

is every body ever work with this feature ?